# npm local modules vs prod

Tags: node.js, module, npm

We are developping two modules depending on another one. Like `A -› B` and `C -› B`

I dug some solutions available now:

## from projects A, B `npm link ../projectC`

- cool:

  - it's a symlink, so changing any file in C is passed on immediately to A and B
- not cool:

  - it requires `../projectC` to be in parent folder (no npm install on prod)
  - it does not show up in the package.json
  - so we need to fiddle with `postinstall` in package.json

## or `npm install ../projectC`

- cool:

  - it's in package.json
- not cool:

  - it requires `../projectC` to be in parent folder (no npm install on prod)
  - we have to do a `npm install` everytime we change C

Comment: Yes that would work as well, but any time I `publish` module C, I have to `npm install` others

Comment: You can [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) (or [npm-watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-watch), or similar...) on dev and auto [update](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/update). on prod you WANT to do it manually.

Answer (score 0):

So the solution was simply `npm link`.

1. You can, in your project C `npm link` (make sure you have a `package.json`).
2. Then in your projects A and B:

   - `npm link module-projectC`
   - also add the dependency in their `package.json`
3. Then you will be able to code comfortably while in development, and do a `npm install` in production scenarios.